# laravel setting up local environment on mac (can't find the proper computer name)

Tags: php, macos, laravel, local

These days I borrowed someone's mac to start learning and using mac.
Anyways, I was able to setup local environment for laravel in windows fine since all I had to do is adding my computer user name into the local array in start.php.

Somehow I couldn't find the proper name on mac to setup the local environment and kept on having issue with database connection.
I tried setting up the production database.php correctly and the site would run fine that's why I know the computer name is the issue when I am trying to setup the local environment.

Anyways, I tried searching up online of course and found a few ways such as going to networking, sharing and command line to get the computer's name but none of them worked.

Can someone give me a hand here please?

Comment: You can find your hostname by running `hostname` from the terminal. You could also set the environment variable `LARAVEL_ENV` to `development` in your `.bash_profile` (or equivalent for your shell).

Comment: @PhpMyCoder :( there is something funny.  Sorry I am really new with this.  After you told me about using hostname which worked really fine when I am at home using wifi.  But somehow I went to a cafe yesterday and database didn't work.  So I went to terminal and check the hostname and somehow it changed. Why is this though? And changing isn't the problem I even added the changed hostname into the file for local environment but it keeps on recognizing production instead.  When I am home my hostname is `Dav-Air` in the cafe hostname is `.local`

Comment: You are correct that your hostname will change if you are on public wifi, for example. The best solution is to add an environment variable. Laravel checks for the presence of the `LARAVEL_ENV` variable on startup and if its set it will automatically use it as the env. If you use bash (the default shell), open up your `~/.bash_profile` and add the line `set LARAVEL_ENV=development` to it. You'll need to re-source this file (or reopen your terminal) with `source ~/.bash_profile`. Now laravel should always be in dev env on your computer.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder I did try what you mentioned.  I opened the terminal and entered `sudo nano ~/.bash_profile` and added `set LARAVEL_ENV=development` then save the file and then reopen the terminal and typed `source ~/.bash_profile` and in my `routes.php` I added `print App::environment();` to check the environment but it still says production instead of any others though.  Is there anything I need to add into the array of the `start.php` this is where I added my hostname before in order for laravel to run local environment.  Because after I tried what you mentioned, still shows production thought

Comment: Seems like I was wrong about the variable name (it's changed since the last time I used laravel), it should be `APP_ENV`. You can (and probably should) [read about `.env` files](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1#environment-configuration) (a feature that laravel provides) and use them. But for now changing your env variable's name to `APP_ENV` should work.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder Alright, thanks thanks.  I will try this out soon :D